# Script using requests library throws "no connection adapters found" error when trying to supply url's from Postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, python-requests

I'm trying to test the validity of URLs stored in `Postgres` database using the `requests` library in a `Python 3.x` script, but am getting the following error:

```
$ python3 test_urlvalid.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_urlvalid.py", line 55, in <module>
    response = requests.get(row)
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '('http://sampleurl.com',)'
```

Here's a snippet of my script:

```
dbconn = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://' + user + ':' + password + '@' + host + ':' + str(port) + '/' + database , echo=False)
dbconnraw = dbconn.raw_connection()
cur = dbconnraw.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT email_domain_url FROM testurlsource')
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    response = requests.get(row)
    urlstat = response.status_code
    if urlstat<400:
        print('valid')
    else:
        print('invalid')
```

The line the error code refers to is:

```
response = requests.get(row)
```

Since the last line of the error code references `%s` in url and `'('http://sampleurl.com',)'` so it's probably related to converting each table entry into a string.

Maybe I need to change something so the characters `"(),'"` are removed when feeding the rows into the script.

I tried using `regex` to do the latter but got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `print(type(row))` in your for-loop, you might find that the variable `row` is probably a `tuple` (or maybe a `list`) with one element inside. The error message seems to suggest that same issue.

So you could try to pass that element to the `requests` call (instead of passing the whole `tuple`), changing this line:

```
response = requests.get(row)
```

to this:

```
response = requests.get(row[0])
```